# VBA code works fine in Excel 2013 but gives error in excel 2016 - Compile error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, excel-2016

I am reaching out to everyone after searching a lot for the solution.
I have a code that works fine in Excel 2013 but when i try to run the same code in excel 2016 it gives me compile error.

This code was developed by someone else and i was just doing minor modification to it. Below is the code. The error is happening due to Environ$ variable. Because that what is highlighted when i press ok button in the given screenshot.

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

I am also attaching error screen shot.

#### Environ$ variable compile error

[image: Environ$ variable compile error]

Any quick help will be much appriciated.

Comment: Click Tools-References in the VB Editor and see which of the checked items is prefixed with 'MISSING:'

Comment: Are aware that if the `xlCellTypeVisible` is a collection of non-contiguous ranges then you have to work with the [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx)?

Comment: While you can host multiple versions of Excel on a single machine, you can only ever have one Outlook version. If you updated Outlook to 2016, then the references to Outlook 2013 are no longer valid.

Comment: @Rory Nothing is prefixed as MISSING.

Comment: Which line causes the error and which references do you have set? (I've never seen this error caused by anything other than a reference issue)

Comment: Did the code originally come from [HERE](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm "Ron de Bruin")?

Comment: @Jeeped I am still in Outlook 2013 but a lot of users have shifted to outlook 2016. So whats the solution?

Comment: @Rory Since this is compile error so i am assuming its caused during compilation of code. Which will not give any specific line for the error.

Comment: Instead of assuming, tell us: does it or doesn't it highlight a line? And please answer the references question.

Comment: @SkipIntro Link is not working

Comment: @Rory it doesn't highlight any line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: @TobySpeight As i am new please suggest what should i do? Like give me some example.

Comment: Apologies, try http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm

Comment: @SkipIntro No the code didn't come from there but i had referenced the code for mailing 1 sheet from the link shared by you. In the code

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match the code in your screenshot with the error message.  [Edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39750882/edit) to include the code that is causing the error.

Comment: @SkipIntro No the code didn't come from there but i had referenced the code for mailing 1 sheet from the link shared by you. In the code .HasVBProject gives error as object not defined

Comment: @SkipIntro I just found that code was taken from the link you had mentioned. Also error is happening because of line
TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
Error is can't find project or library

Comment: @Comintern i have corrected the error screen shot as per the given code.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same error from Ron de Bruin `rangetohtml(rng as range)`.

I have resolved.

If you go back to the code before
On Error Resume Next
and comment out.

run and you will see it can't find the `drawingobjects.visible`.

to fix.

go to `file/options/formulas/`

make sure it isn't R1C1  - uncheck this box.

Mine worked fine after this.